# Кнопка печати Grid

Tags: c#, wpf, печать

Приветствую! Вопрос наверное дико простой, но я что-то туплю.
На какой-то форме (не главной) есть простая кнопка печати грида:

```
private void print_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PrintDialog printdlg = new PrintDialog();
        if (printdlg.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            printdlg.PrintVisual(grid1, "Печать");
        }
    }
```

Всё хорошо, но при появлении принтдиалога на заднем плане открывается мэйнформа. Что сделать, чтобы такого не было?

Пока решил костылём: добавил для мэйнформы Visibility.Hidden при открытии другой c принтдиалогом, и Visible при её закрытии, но всё равно как-то не по феншую, может кто подскажет нормальный вариант?

Comment: Такого быть не должно. Приведите какой-нибудь воспроизводящий код, может?

Comment: Может есть альтернативный вариант?

Comment: Ну, хм. Может и есть более сложный альтернативный, но этот вариант должен работать. Представьте себе, что вы забиваете гвозди молотком, но по ошибке держите его не той стороной. В этом случае вам нужно не искать другой инструмент, а разобраться, что с молотком не в порядке.

Comment: Ну, если PrintDialog расковырять, там есть отсылки к основному окну приложения, но явного Show на нём, конечно, и в помине нет. Какая-то "пляска" с окошками у Вас и без окна печати явно должна происходить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну, так как никто не ответил, пусть будет мой вариант:
добавил для мэйнформы Visibility.Hidden при открытии другой c принтдиалогом, и Visible при её закрытии.